library "libmediapipe_tasks_vision_jni.so" not found
For my final project, I will be developing an object recognition application and currently, I am watching tutorials to learn application development. However, I encountered an error that I couldn't solve. Despite implementing the library, the application doesn't recognize the library and thus, doesn't work. How can I resolve this issue? The library I intend to use is Mediapipe. The library files are not included in the application files. I tried to download from GitHub, but I couldn't find which file to add. Here it is the Log of the program
enter image description here
Here this is my MainActivity.java
package com.example.objectdetection;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;


import com.google.mediapipe.tasks.vision.core.RunningMode;

import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.Permission;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ObjectDetectorHelper.DetectorListener {

    private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 123;
    public static final int IMAGE_CAPTURE_CODE = 654;
    private static final int PERMISSION_CODE = 321;
    ImageView innerImage;
    private Uri image_uri;
    private final float CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD = 0.3f;

    ObjectDetectorHelper objectDetectorHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        innerImage = findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        innerImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });

        innerImage.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED || checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
                        String[] permission = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                        requestPermissions(permission, PERMISSION_CODE);
                    }
                    else {
                        openCamera();
                    }
                }

                else {
                    openCamera();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        objectDetectorHelper = new ObjectDetectorHelper(0.5f, ObjectDetectorHelper.MAX_RESULTS_DEFAULT, ObjectDetectorHelper.DELEGATE_CPU, "fruits.tflite", RunningMode.IMAGE, getApplicationContext(), this);

    }

    //open camera to capture picture
    private void openCamera() {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "New Picture");
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From the Camera");
        image_uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, image_uri);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, IMAGE_CAPTURE_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
            image_uri = data.getData();
            doInference();
        }

        if (requestCode == IMAGE_CAPTURE_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            doInference();
        }
    }

    //Passing image to the model, getting the results and drawing rectangles
    public void  doInference(){
        Bitmap bitmap = uriToBitmap(image_uri);
        innerImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        //Bitmap rotatedBmp = rotateBitmap(bitmap);

        ObjectDetectorHelper.ResultBundle resultBundle =  objectDetectorHelper.detectImage(bitmap);
        if (resultBundle != null){
            Log.d("tryRes", resultBundle.getInferenceTime()+"");
        }
    }


    //TODO rotate image if image captured on sumsong devices
    //Most phone cameras are landscape, meaning if you take the photo in portrait, the resulting photos will be rotated 90 degrees.
    public Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap input){
        String[] orientationColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION};
        Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(image_uri, orientationColumn, null, null, null);
        int orientation = -1;
        if (cur != null && cur.moveToFirst()) {
            orientation = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(orientationColumn[0]));
        }
        Log.d("tryOrientation",orientation+"");
        Matrix rotationMatrix = new Matrix();
        rotationMatrix.setRotate(orientation);
        Bitmap cropped = Bitmap.createBitmap(input,0,0, input.getWidth(), input.getHeight(), rotationMatrix, true);
        return cropped;
    }


    //takes image uri as input and return that image in a bitmap format
    private Bitmap uriToBitmap(Uri selectedFileUri) {
        try {
            ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor =
                    getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(selectedFileUri, "r");
            FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);

            parcelFileDescriptor.close();
            return image;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return  null;
    }

    //If user gives permission then launch camera
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(requestCode == PERMISSION_CODE && grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            openCamera();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(String var1, int var2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onResults(ObjectDetectorHelper.ResultBundle var1) {

    }
}


Here this is my build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {

    // 33
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.objectdetection"
        minSdkVersion 24
        // 33
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    aaptOptions{
        noCompress "tflite"
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.mediapipe:tasks-vision:0.10.0'

}


And also, I got an error when I change the compileSdkVersion to the 33 which is MALFORMED error
enter image description here
